# NVD3 Line Chart doesn't display when data passed using ajax - data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to implement an NVD3 line chart using AJAX to load JSON data for 3 series.

I am using .NET MVC to expose my formatted JSON at /Home/GetJsonMovingAverages.

If I copy and paste this data, it all loads correctly on the graph, but by loading it via Ajax causes it to break without apparent error.

I've tried alerting the datato prove its loaded, using callbacks to enforce waiting, disabling async in the .ajax method, and a plethora of other checks, none of which have helped me identify or expose the problem.

It's simply beyond me.

The below code grabs the JSON using d3, and then tries to render it on the graph. This is as close to the demo code as I can possibly make it. I also render the JSON data to the page to indicate when it's loaded and that it's correct. (it takes ~5-10 seconds)

When the JSON appears on the page it's properly formatted and correct, but no chart appears.

**EDIT : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QsHw4/6123/)**

NOTE: Now found it gives error: **TypeError: data.map is not a function** on nv.d3.js (line 5476, col 23) **but only when using ajax**. (m.map in nv.d3.min.js)

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Load chart data
        d3.json('/Home/GetJsonMovingAverages', function (data) {
            // Renders a line chart
            (function () {
                nv.addGraph(function () {               //This adds the chart to a global rendering queue.
                    var chart = nv.models.lineChart();  //Create instance of nvd3 lineChart

                    $("p.jsonData").html(data); // What's going on here?!

                    chart.xAxis
                        .axisLabel("Date")              //Set X-axis attributes
                        .tickFormat(function (d) { return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y')(new Date(d)); });;             

                    chart.yAxis
                        .axisLabel("Moving Average(s)"); //Set Y-Axis attributes.
                        //.tickFormat(d3.format("d"));    //Set Y-Axis label formatting.

                    d3.select("svg")                    //Select the document's <svg> element
                        .datum(data)                    //Attach data to the <svg> element.
                        .transition().duration(500).call(chart);    //Define transition and pass the d3.selection to our lineChart.

                    nv.utils.windowResize(              //Updates the window resize event callback.
                            function () {
                                chart.update();         //Renders the chart when window is resized.
                            }
                        );

                    return chart;   //Must return the enclosed chart variable so the global rendering queue can store it.
                });
            })();
        });
    });
})(window.jQuery);
```

However if I copy the data returned on the page, and paste it identically into the method as such, then it works completely fine:

```
d3.select("svg")                    //Select the document's <svg> element
    .datum([{ key: "30 Day", color: "#ffaa00", values: [{ x: 1419984000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1418342400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1417737600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1417132800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1416873600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1416787200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1416528000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1416441600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1416355200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1416268800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1416182400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1415923200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1415836800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1415750400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1415664000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1415577600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1415318400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1415232000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1415145600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1415059200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1414972800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1414713600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1414627200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1414540800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1414454400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1414368000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1414105200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1414018800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1413932400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1413846000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1413759600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1413500400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1413414000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1413327600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1413241200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1413154800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1412895600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1412809200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1412722800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1412636400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1412550000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1412290800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1412204400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1412118000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1412031600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1411945200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1411686000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1411599600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1411513200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1411426800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1411340400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1411081200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1410994800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1410908400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1410822000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1410735600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1410476400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1410390000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1410303600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1410217200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1410130800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1409871600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1409785200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1409698800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1409612400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1409526000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1409266800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1409180400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1409094000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1409007600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1408662000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1408575600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1408489200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1408402800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1408316400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1408057200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1407970800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1407884400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1407798000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1407711600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1407452400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1407366000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1407279600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1407193200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1407106800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1406847600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1406761200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1406674800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1406588400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1406502000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1406242800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1406156400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1406070000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1405983600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1405897200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1405638000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1405551600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1405465200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1405378800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1405292400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1405033200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1404946800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1404860400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1404774000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1404687600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1404428400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1404342000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1404255600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1404169200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1404082800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1403823600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1403737200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1403650800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1403564400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1403478000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1403218800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1403132400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1403046000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1402959600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1402873200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1402614000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1402527600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1402441200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1402354800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1402268400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1402095600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1402009200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1401922800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1401836400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1401750000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1401663600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1401490800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1401404400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1401318000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1401231600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1401145200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1400799600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1400713200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1400626800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1400540400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1400454000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1400194800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1400108400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1400022000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1399935600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1399849200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1399590000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1399503600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1399417200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1399330800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1398985200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1398898800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1398812400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1398726000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1398639600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1398380400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1398294000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1398207600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1398121200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1397948400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1397775600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1397689200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1397602800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1397516400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1397430000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1397170800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1397084400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1396998000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1396911600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1396825200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1396566000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1396479600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1396393200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1396306800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1396220400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1395964800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1395878400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1395792000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1395705600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1395619200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1395360000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1395273600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1395187200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1395100800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1395014400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1394755200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1394668800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1394582400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1394496000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1394323200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1394150400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1394064000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1393977600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1393891200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1393804800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1393718400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1393632000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1393545600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1393459200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1393372800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1393286400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1393200000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1392940800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1392854400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1392768000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1392681600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1392595200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1392336000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1392249600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1392163200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1392076800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1391990400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1391731200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1391644800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1391558400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1391472000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1391385600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1391299200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1391212800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1391126400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1391040000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1390953600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1390867200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1390780800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1390521600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1390435200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1390348800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1390262400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1390176000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1389916800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1389830400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1389744000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1389657600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1389571200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1389312000000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1389225600000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1389139200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1389052800000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1388966400000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1388707200000, y: 30.0 }, { x: 1388534400000, y: 30.0 }] }, { key: "60 Day", color: "#00ffaa", values: [{ x: 1419984000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1418342400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1417737600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1417132800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1416873600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1416787200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1416528000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1416441600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1416355200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1416268800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1416182400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1415923200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1415836800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1415750400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1415664000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1415577600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1415318400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1415232000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1415145600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1415059200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1414972800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1414713600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1414627200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1414540800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1414454400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1414368000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1414105200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1414018800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1413932400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1413846000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1413759600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1413500400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1413414000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1413327600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1413241200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1413154800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1412895600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1412809200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1412722800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1412636400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1412550000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1412290800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1412204400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1412118000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1412031600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1411945200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1411686000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1411599600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1411513200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1411426800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1411340400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1411081200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1410994800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1410908400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1410822000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1410735600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1410476400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1410390000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1410303600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1410217200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1410130800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1409871600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1409785200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1409698800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1409612400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1409526000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1409266800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1409180400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1409094000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1409007600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1408662000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1408575600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1408489200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1408402800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1408316400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1408057200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1407970800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1407884400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1407798000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1407711600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1407452400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1407366000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1407279600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1407193200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1407106800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1406847600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1406761200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1406674800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1406588400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1406502000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1406242800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1406156400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1406070000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1405983600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1405897200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1405638000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1405551600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1405465200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1405378800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1405292400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1405033200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1404946800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1404860400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1404774000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1404687600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1404428400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1404342000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1404255600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1404169200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1404082800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1403823600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1403737200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1403650800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1403564400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1403478000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1403218800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1403132400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1403046000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1402959600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1402873200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1402614000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1402527600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1402441200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1402354800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1402268400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1402095600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1402009200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1401922800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1401836400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1401750000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1401663600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1401490800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1401404400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1401318000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1401231600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1401145200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1400799600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1400713200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1400626800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1400540400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1400454000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1400194800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1400108400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1400022000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1399935600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1399849200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1399590000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1399503600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1399417200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1399330800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1398985200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1398898800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1398812400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1398726000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1398639600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1398380400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1398294000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1398207600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1398121200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1397948400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1397775600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1397689200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1397602800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1397516400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1397430000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1397170800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1397084400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1396998000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1396911600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1396825200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1396566000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1396479600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1396393200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1396306800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1396220400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1395964800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1395878400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1395792000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1395705600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1395619200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1395360000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1395273600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1395187200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1395100800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1395014400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1394755200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1394668800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1394582400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1394496000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1394323200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1394150400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1394064000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1393977600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1393891200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1393804800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1393718400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1393632000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1393545600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1393459200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1393372800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1393286400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1393200000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1392940800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1392854400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1392768000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1392681600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1392595200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1392336000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1392249600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1392163200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1392076800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1391990400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1391731200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1391644800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1391558400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1391472000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1391385600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1391299200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1391212800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1391126400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1391040000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1390953600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1390867200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1390780800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1390521600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1390435200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1390348800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1390262400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1390176000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1389916800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1389830400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1389744000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1389657600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1389571200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1389312000000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1389225600000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1389139200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1389052800000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1388966400000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1388707200000, y: 60.0 }, { x: 1388534400000, y: 60.0 }] }, { key: "90 Day", color: "#aa00ff", values: [{ x: 1419984000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1418342400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1417737600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1417132800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1416873600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1416787200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1416528000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1416441600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1416355200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1416268800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1416182400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1415923200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1415836800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1415750400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1415664000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1415577600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1415318400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1415232000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1415145600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1415059200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1414972800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1414713600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1414627200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1414540800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1414454400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1414368000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1414105200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1414018800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1413932400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1413846000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1413759600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1413500400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1413414000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1413327600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1413241200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1413154800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1412895600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1412809200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1412722800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1412636400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1412550000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1412290800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1412204400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1412118000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1412031600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1411945200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1411686000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1411599600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1411513200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1411426800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1411340400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1411081200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1410994800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1410908400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1410822000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1410735600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1410476400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1410390000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1410303600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1410217200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1410130800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1409871600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1409785200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1409698800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1409612400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1409526000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1409266800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1409180400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1409094000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1409007600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1408662000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1408575600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1408489200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1408402800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1408316400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1408057200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1407970800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1407884400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1407798000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1407711600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1407452400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1407366000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1407279600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1407193200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1407106800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1406847600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1406761200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1406674800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1406588400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1406502000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1406242800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1406156400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1406070000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1405983600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1405897200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1405638000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1405551600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1405465200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1405378800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1405292400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1405033200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1404946800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1404860400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1404774000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1404687600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1404428400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1404342000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1404255600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1404169200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1404082800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1403823600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1403737200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1403650800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1403564400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1403478000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1403218800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1403132400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1403046000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1402959600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1402873200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1402614000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1402527600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1402441200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1402354800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1402268400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1402095600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1402009200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1401922800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1401836400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1401750000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1401663600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1401490800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1401404400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1401318000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1401231600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1401145200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1400799600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1400713200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1400626800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1400540400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1400454000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1400194800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1400108400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1400022000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1399935600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1399849200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1399590000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1399503600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1399417200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1399330800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1398985200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1398898800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1398812400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1398726000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1398639600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1398380400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1398294000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1398207600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1398121200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1397948400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1397775600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1397689200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1397602800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1397516400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1397430000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1397170800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1397084400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1396998000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1396911600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1396825200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1396566000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1396479600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1396393200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1396306800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1396220400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1395964800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1395878400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1395792000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1395705600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1395619200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1395360000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1395273600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1395187200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1395100800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1395014400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1394755200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1394668800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1394582400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1394496000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1394323200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1394150400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1394064000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1393977600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1393891200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1393804800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1393718400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1393632000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1393545600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1393459200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1393372800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1393286400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1393200000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1392940800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1392854400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1392768000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1392681600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1392595200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1392336000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1392249600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1392163200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1392076800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1391990400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1391731200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1391644800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1391558400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1391472000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1391385600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1391299200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1391212800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1391126400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1391040000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1390953600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1390867200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1390780800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1390521600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1390435200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1390348800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1390262400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1390176000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1389916800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1389830400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1389744000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1389657600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1389571200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1389312000000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1389225600000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1389139200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1389052800000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1388966400000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1388707200000, y: 90.0 }, { x: 1388534400000, y: 90.0 }] }])                    //Attach data to the <svg> element.
    .transition().duration(500).call(chart);    //Define transition and pass the d3.selection to our lineChart.
```

**If unclear, my question is: How can I load an NVD3 Line Chart using AJAX? (without these problems)** Many thanks in advance for any suggestions/assistance you can provide.

**EDIT 2: New Code following answer + example of working hardcoded JSON**

```
d3.json('http://localhost:50786/Home/GetJsonMovingAverages', function (data) {
    // Renders a line chart

    nv.addGraph(function () {
        var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .options({
            margin: { left: 10, bottom: 10 },
            x: function (d, i) { return i },
            showXAxis: true,
            showYAxis: true,
            tooltips: true,
            x: function (d, i) { return i },
            transitionDuration: 500
        });

        chart.useInteractiveGuideline(true);


        chart.xAxis.axisLabel("Date") //Set X-axis attributes
.tickFormat(function (d) {
    return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y')(new Date(d));
});
        chart.yAxis
            .axisLabel("Moving Average(s)"); //Set Y-Axis attributes.
        //.tickFormat(d3.format("d"));    //Set Y-Axis label formatting.

        d3.select('#nvd3-line svg')    //Select the <svg> element you want to render the chart in.   
           .datum([{
               "key": "30 Day",
               "values": [{
                   "x": 1417132800000,
                   "y": 35
               }, {
                   "x": 1417737600000,
                   "y": 30
               }, {
                   "x": 1418342400000,
                   "y": 40
               }, {
                   "x": 1419984000000,
                   "y": 50
               }]
           }, {
               "key": "60 Day",
               "values": [{
                   "x": 1417132800000,
                   "y": 40
               }, {
                   "x": 1417737600000,
                   "y": 50
               }, {
                   "x": 1418342400000,
                   "y": 45
               }, {
                   "x": 1419984000000,
                   "y": 40
               }]
           }, {
               "key": "90 Day",
               "values": [{
                   "x": 1417132800000,
                   "y": 50
               }, {
                   "x": 1417737600000,
                   "y": 70
               }, {
                   "x": 1418342400000,
                   "y": 50
               }, {
                   "x": 1419984000000,
                   "y": 30
               }]
           }])                  // WORKING - NOT AJAX //Populate the <svg> element with chart data...
           //.datum(data)       // NOT WORKING - AJAX //Populate the <svg> element with chart data... 
           .call(chart);          //Finally, render the chart!

        // THIS CODE ONLY NEEDS TO BE INITIATED ONCE
        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
        nv.utils.windowResize(function () { d3.select('#nvd3-line svg').call(chart) });

        chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function (e) {
            nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e));
        });

        return chart;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
jQuery.parseJSON(myAjaxLoadedData);
```

It appears the issue with the ajax loaded data is that it was a string. I'm rather confused as I followed all examples I could find and they appeared to load it the same was as I was.

Here is my full working code:

```
// Load chart data
d3.json('http://localhost:50786/Home/GetJsonMovingAverages', function (error, myData) {
    // Renders a line chart
    (function () {
        nv.addGraph(function () {               //This adds the chart to a global rendering queue.
            var chart = nv.models.lineChart()  //Create instance of nvd3 lineChart
                .useInteractiveGuideline(true);
            chart.xAxis
                .axisLabel("Date")              //Set X-axis attributes
                .tickFormat(function (d) { return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y')(new Date(d)); });
            chart.yAxis
                .axisLabel("Moving Average(s)"); //Set Y-Axis attributes.

            d3.select("svg")                    //Select the document's <svg> element
                .datum(jQuery.parseJSON(myData))                    //Attach data to the <svg> element.
                .call(chart);    //Define transition and pass the d3.selection to our lineChart.

            // THIS CODE ONLY NEEDS TO BE INITIATED ONCE
            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
            //nv.utils.windowResize(function () { d3.select('svg').call(chart); });

            //chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function (e) {
            //    nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e));
            return chart;   //Must return the enclosed chart variable so the global rendering queue can store it.
            //});
        });
    })();
});
```

Thanks Very Much to Engl12 for his effort towards this solution

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is invalid, although NVD3 likes it in a few different formats, the d3.json ajax call likes it in a specific way.

Your missing double quotation marks around your strings, if you format your JSON to look like the following, it will work when you pull it from your AJAX call.

**Snippet of your JSON in the correct format -**

```
[
    {
        "key": "30 Day",
        "color": "#ffaa00",
        "values": [
            {
                "x": 1419984000000,
                "y": 30
            },
            {
                "x": 1418342400000,
                "y": 30
            },
            {
                "x": 1417737600000,
                "y": 30
            },
            {
                "x": 1417132800000,
                "y": 30
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Result - Valid JSON

Comment: This is the format my JSON was originally in, I shall re-check my code with the format you've provided now but I don't think it will work as it was manually removing the quotes on property names that allowed data to display in the first place.

Comment: I have returned to that format and also checked the new output is valid with a JSON validator (JSONLint). It matches your spec, and also doesn't work. I tried also changing the variable name I use for data from 'data' to 'myData' to ensure variable masking wasn't happening.
Using the 'ajax loaded' data on the .lineChart() gives me "TypeError: data.map is not a function
state.disabled = [-->]data.map(function(d) { return !!d.disabled });
and using it on a .lineWithFocusChart() gives me "TypeError: data.filter is not a function
if (!data || !data.length || !data.filter(function(d) { return d..."

Comment: Can you do a JSFiddle?

Comment: I can attempt to, but my code works fine when I pass the data explicitly or through any local method. It only fails when I try to load the data via ajax on my local VS development server and then sue it directly. It's the action of ajax loading that is the issue I think. It works completely fine if I use ajax to set a div contents to the data, and then copy and paste that to the .datum() method of d3.select()

Comment: I have made the JSFiddle, but it works completely fine whereas my version does not. Both the JSON format that I originally used, and the format you suggested, work correctly in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/QsHw4/6117/

Comment: I have switched to jQuery .ajax() and have now managed to reproduce the error: http://jsfiddle.net/QsHw4/6123/

Comment: I have reposted another answer, please try it and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Please try this edited script to generate your graphs and grab JSON, it works for me with the  JSON data from your JSFiddle.

```
  d3.json('........php', function (data) {
            // Renders a line chart



                        nv.addGraph(function() {
                        var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                        .options({
                        margin: {left: 10, bottom: 10},
                        x: function(d,i) { return i},
                        showXAxis: true,
                        showYAxis: true,
                        tooltips: true,
                        x: function(d,i) { return i},
                        transitionDuration: 500
                        });

                       chart.useInteractiveGuideline(true);


                     chart.xAxis.axisLabel("Date") //Set X-axis attributes
            .tickFormat(function (d) {
                return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y')(new Date(d));
            });
                    chart.yAxis
                        .axisLabel("Moving Average(s)"); //Set Y-Axis attributes.
                        //.tickFormat(d3.format("d"));    //Set Y-Axis label formatting.

                     d3.select('#chart1 svg')    //Select the <svg> element you want to render the chart in.   
                        .datum(data)         //Populate the <svg> element with chart data...
                        .call(chart);          //Finally, render the chart!





                        // THIS CODE ONLY NEEDS TO BE INITIATED ONCE
                        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
                        nv.utils.windowResize(function() { d3.select('#chart1 svg').call(chart) });

                        chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) {
                        nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e));
                         });






                        return chart;
                        });
                        });
```

Call the chart in the html  -

```
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td id="chart1">
                <svg></svg>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your efforts. Unfortunately when using your code letter for letter (excl. ID of chart container) I still receive error: TypeError: data.map is not a function in nv.d3.js (line 5476, col 23)
NOTE: Remember I believe ajax is the cause. I can plug the data in via copy/paste and it works fine. In both my original method, and your method.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the new code I am using based on this answer. See Edit 2.
I can't use the ajax populated data variable. But if I copy and paste the contents of the data variable directly to the .datum() method then it works fine.